# Asteroids Ball Angle Calculation

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

Right now I am working on making the classic game Asteroids. I have gotten the ship to move 360 degrees using the arrow keys. However, when I try to shoot the balls out of the ship at that angle, they only leave at 45 degree increments. I think that means there is something wrong with my math in the ball class:

```
public Ball(double ballAngle){

    angle = ballAngle;

    xRatio = Math.cos((angle + 90) * 3.14 / 180);
    yRatio = Math.sin((angle + 90) * 3.14 / 180);

    xChange = xRatio * speed;
    yChange = yRatio * speed;

}

public void update(){

    x = (int) Math.round(x + xChange);
    y = (int) Math.round(y + yChange);

}
```

However, I can't seem to find what is going on. I have tried debugging it by printing the values an following them step by step, but still can't solve it. Here is the rest of my code incase you need to see it.

Main Game Class:

```
package Asteroids;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Asteroids extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

public final static int BOX_WIDTH = 600;
public final static int BOX_HEIGHT = 600;

public final static int UPDATE_RATE = 300;

public final static double shipSpeed = 1;

ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

int i = 0;

int ballCount = 0;

boolean spawn = false;

Ship ship = new Ship(BOX_WIDTH / 2,BOX_HEIGHT / 2);

public Asteroids(){

    //Set window size
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOX_WIDTH,BOX_HEIGHT));

    //Start game thread
    Thread gameThread = new Thread() {

        public void run(){

            while(true){

                ship.update();

                for (int j=0; j<ballCount; j++){

                    balls.get(j).update();

                }

                if(spawn){

                    i++;

                }

                if(i % 100 == 0){

                    balls.add(new Ball(ship.getAngle()));
                    ballCount ++;

                }

                repaint();

                try {Thread.sleep(1000 / UPDATE_RATE);} 
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

            }
        }

    };

    gameThread.start();

}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.black);

    g.fillRect(0, 0, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);

    for (int j=0; j<ballCount; j++){

        balls.get(j).draw(g);

    }

    ship.draw(g);

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

        ship.setSpeed(-shipSpeed);

    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

        ship.setSpeed(shipSpeed);

    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){

        spawn = true;

    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

        ship.setSpeed(0);

    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

        ship.setSpeed(0);

    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){

        spawn = false;

    }

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public static void main(String[] args) {

     javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                //Create Frame
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("ASTEROIDS");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Asteroids asteroids = new Asteroids();
                frame.setContentPane(asteroids); 
                frame.setSize(BOX_WIDTH,BOX_HEIGHT);
                frame.pack();
                frame.addKeyListener(asteroids);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }

        });

}

public int getBoxHeight(){

    return BOX_HEIGHT;

}

public int getBoxWidth(){

    return BOX_WIDTH;

}

}
```

Ship Class:

```
package Asteroids;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ship {

Random rng = new Random();

int r = rng.nextInt(256);
int g = rng.nextInt(256);
int b = rng.nextInt(256);

Color color = new Color(r,g,b);

double speed = 0;

double angle = 0;

final static int shipLength = 20;
final static int shipAngle = 40;

static int x;
static int y;

int point1x;
int point2x;
int point3x;

int point1y;
int point2y;
int point3y;

public Ship(int xPos, int yPos){

    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;

    point1x = x;
    point2x = (int) Math.round( x - (Math.tan(shipAngle * 6.28 / 360) * shipLength));
    point3x = (int) Math.round( x + (Math.tan(shipAngle * 6.28 / 360) * shipLength));

    point1y = y - shipLength;
    point2y = y + shipLength;
    point3y = y + shipLength;

}

public void update(){

    angle  = angle + speed;

    if(angle < 0){

        angle = angle + 360;

    }

    else if(angle >= 360){

        angle = angle - 360;

    }

}

public void draw(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(color);

    point1x = x - (int) Math.round( Math.sin(angle * 6.28 / 360) * shipLength);
    point2x = x + (int) Math.round( Math.sin((angle + shipAngle) * 6.28 / 360) * shipLength);
    point3x = x + (int) Math.round( Math.sin((angle - shipAngle) * 6.28 / 360) * shipLength);

    point1y = y + (int) Math.round( Math.cos(angle * 6.28 / 360) * shipLength);
    point2y = y + (int) Math.round( Math.cos((angle + 180 + shipAngle) * 6.28 / 360) * shipLength);
    point3y = y + (int) Math.round( Math.cos((angle - 180 - shipAngle) *    6.28 / 360) * shipLength);

    int xpoints[] = {point1x, point2x, point3x};
    int ypoints[] = {point1y, point2y, point3y};
    int npoints = 3;

    g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);

}

public void setSpeed(double s){

    speed = s;

}

public static int getX(){

    return x;

}

public static int getY(){

    return y;

}

public double getAngle(){

    return angle;

}

}
```

Ball Class:

```
package Asteroids;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ball {

int x = Ship.getX();
int y = Ship.getY();

double angle;

double xRatio;
double yRatio;

double xChange;
double yChange;

final static int speed = 1;

final static int diameter = 5;

public Ball(double ballAngle){

    angle = ballAngle;

    xRatio = Math.cos((angle + 90) * 3.14 / 180);
    yRatio = Math.sin((angle + 90) * 3.14 / 180);

    xChange = xRatio * speed;
    yChange = yRatio * speed;

}

public void update(){

    x = (int) Math.round(x + xChange);
    y = (int) Math.round(y + yChange);

}

public void draw(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.white);

    g.fillOval(x - diameter/2, y - diameter/2, diameter, diameter);

}

}
```

Comment: Nobody's going to want to help you if they have to read through hundreds of lines of code. Please only include the relevant content or break your programs down into the smallest possible code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect its a rounding error. You're storing x and y as int primitives, but then adding doubles to it, storing it back in the int. If you changed x and y to be doubles, and then round them only before you display the location, you shouldn't have this problem